# Azure Function CosmosDBInput Binding doesn't return value

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following Azure function:

```
private const string PartitionKey = "/westus2";

public class League
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<string> GameIds { get; set; }
}

[Function("AddGame")]
public async Task<AddGameMultiResponse> AddGame(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "addgame/{leagueId}")] HttpRequestData req,
    [CosmosDBInput(databaseName: "MyDB",
        collectionName: "Leagues",
        PartitionKey = PartitionKey,
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")] IEnumerable<League> leagues,
    [CosmosDBInput(databaseName: "MyDB",
        collectionName: "Leagues",
        Id = "{leagueId}",
        PartitionKey = PartitionKey,
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")] League league)
{
}
```

And when I call it through Postman with the following URI:

```
http://localhost:7071/api/addgame/5fa8c927-15ad-4fd2-8b9d-4d7b11723021
```

I see that leagues has one item that has property:

```
id [string]: "5fa8c927-15ad-4fd2-8b9d-4d7b11723021"
```

Yet league is null.  Looking in the data explorer, I see:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
Seems like this works:

```
   [CosmosDBInput(databaseName: "MyDB",
        collectionName: "Leagues",
        PartitionKey = PartitionKey,
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
        SqlQuery = "SELECT * from c WHERE c.id = {leagueId}")] IEnumerable<League> matchingLeagues
```

So now I feel like there must be a bug in the CosmosDBInput binding...

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes please post the solution as an answer, this will help the community Members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PartitionKey` might be the key here. What value are you passing?

The single item read:

```
[CosmosDBInput(databaseName: "MyDB",
        collectionName: "Leagues",
        Id = "{leagueId}",
        PartitionKey = PartitionKey,
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")] League league)
```

Requires both `Id` and `PartitionKey` to be able to find the item. You got the `Id`, but what about the `PartitionKey`? Is the container partitioned by `/id`? If yes, then the `PartitionKey` should also have `"{leagueId}"`.

The reason for `League league` to be `null` is simply that the Id/PartitionKey values you are setting do not match with an existing document.

Comment: See the very first line:  private const string PartitionKey = "/westus2";
When I use the sql query, it works fine with that partition key.  But the Id/Partition key combo does not work

Comment: If you inspect the document you are trying to read, does it have "/westus2" (including the "/") in the property that is defined as the Partition Key? If not (maybe the value is "westus2"?), then that is the reason, no document exists with the defined id and PartitionKey

Comment: The screenshot above shows the document, it doesn't have a Partition key property.  I thought that the CosmosDbOutput attribute listed the partition key property, and that was enough.  I take it then that with the sqlquery, the partitionkey field is ignored?  Do you know what capitalization the partition key field has to be?  Even though Id is uppercase in the attribute, it is expecting lowercase in the property.  Should it be PartitionKey, partitionKey, or partitionkey?

Comment: The Partition Key property is the property that is defined in the Container. If your Container was created with "/MyProperty" as Partition Key Definition, then the Partition Key Value is the value of that property in a document. In the screenshot "/westus2" is your Partition Key Definition. It is expected the document has such a property, it is not your case.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have made a mistake setting the Partition Key Definition (`/westus2`), and it should be some of the properties in the document, like `/id`. In which case, the `PartitionKey` should have the value of the Id.

Comment: ohhh, that makes a lot more sense.  Since c# can't have a property on an item that has a slash in the name, /westus2 doesn't make sense for a definition name.  I'll try that out.

Comment: That works!  I created the collection with Partition Key as "PartitionKey" and I set the property PartitionKey of the object to "westus2", and used that as the value of the CosmosDBAttribute ParitionKey.  Would it be possible to change the description of the field title when creating a new collection?  As it stands, it is unclear it means the name of the partition key field, as opposed to the actual partition key.  A helpful blurb on mouseover would help as well.